# iPython: how do I count the number of times a string appears in a cell?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I have a data frame with the columns `Movie Title` and `Cast` that looks like this:

[image: picture of csv]

Column 1 has the name of the movie, whilst Column 2 lists the full cast of the film. The cast has been taken from the site TMDB.

Column 2 has the pattern: `'cast_id': {cast_id_number}`, `'character': {character_name}`, `'credit_id': {credit_number}`, `'gender': {gender_identifier}`, etc.

I am writing a project for school looking at the gender split in different films. I therefore want to create a column that counts the number of male/female actors in a specific film. e.g:

```
Movie Title | Cast | No. of Males | No. of Females
Toy Story   | .... | 3            | 7
```

However, I'm not sure how to go about doing this. I've tried using `str.count` but it keeps returning all values as 0, even if I can see a cell contains `'gender': 2` or `'gender': 1`.

I'm assuming it may need an if loop counter that reads the string in each row and adds 1 every time it encounters `'gender': 2` but have no idea how to implement this.

Comment: Could you post a few rows of the CSV (or imported DataFrame) as text, not images, or provide a download link to the data?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler you can download the data here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TOAv0NXZ7w6pgCt3K7e8h3UiwuEl-UD1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate over each cast member for each movie and determine how many cast members are female/male. Something like this should work:

```
def gender_ct(data, gender=1):
    return len([1 for x in data if x['gender'] == gender])

df['No. of Females'] = df['Cast'].apply(gender_ct, gender=1)
df['No. of Males'] = df['Cast'].apply(gender_ct, gender=2)
```